# How to check if input contains all 26 chars

Tags: text-processing

I got a input file which contains one char per line
I want to check if the file has exactly all 26 letters.
I found that `uniq -d` can help to get the repeated one.
But how to find out the missing character? Would `grep` be useful?

Comment: Better... so you have to find the missing letters or only how many of them are missing ?

Comment: I want to know the exactly char that missing, just like the output of *uniq -d*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with `grep`:

```
printf %s\\n {a..z} | grep -vf infile
```

or with `sort`/`join` and a modern shell:

```
sort -u infile | join -v2 - <(printf %s\\n {a..z})
```

or, similarly, with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{z[$0]++;next}!($0 in z)' infile <(printf %s\\n {a..z})
```

Comment: You can't use both `-a` and `-v` to `join`.  Did you test that command?

Comment: `$ sort -u infile | join -a 1 -v 2 - <(printf %s\\n {a..z})` (newline)
`join: the -a and -v options are mutually exclusive`

Comment: [POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) show them as mutually exclusive options, also....

Answer (score 2):

... or with `comm`:

```
printf %s\\n {a..z} | comm -23 - <(sort infile)
```

Here we are suppressing comm's output except for lines that are unique to "file 1". File 1 is the `printf` alphabet; File 2 is the (required-to-be) sorted input. Any letters that are missing from the File 2 'infile' will be reported by comm.